# SIM800L Blank SMS issue

Tags: character-encoding, embedded, sms, at-command, sim800

I am using a [SIM800L module](http://simcom.ee/modules/gsm-gprs/sim800/) with a Texas Instrument Launchpad, with a MSP430G2553 microcontroller, not using an external library for SIM800L.

**Problem Statement:**
A Simple text message (SMS with Text Mode) is sent, received as a blank message on cellphone.

**SIM details:**

**1. SIM 1** : Location: India. Operator: AirTel, 4G compatible SIM Card.
 **2. SIM 2** : Location: India. Operator: Tata Docomo, 3G compatible SIM card.

**What I know already:**

- UART Drivers in firmware are tested and working, non-polling, interrupt driven.
- No blocking time delays added as a substitute to read responses of AT commands. I read the response and proceed only if positive acknowledgement is received, `<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>` for most of the commands.
- I have confirmed the data bits transmitted and received on Tx-Rx pins by means of an oscilloscope. Everything seems as expected, including voltage levels.

**What I have read:**

- Some speculation through unofficial sources (Of course forums) that SIM800L is only 2G compatible.
- (Shallow reading from wikipedia) I have read through [GSM 3.38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) and [GSM 3.40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40), and the [Data Coding Scheme section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40#Data_Coding_Scheme) for understanding how the encoding of text is handled in suited/relevant AT command (AT+CSMP).
- Various forums including the ones for arduino with which SIM800L modules are very popularly used.

**Related posts on Stackoverflow:**

- [Recieving Blank SMS SIM800 using AT Commands and Python on Raspberry Pi 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146737/recieving-blank-sms-sim800-using-at-commands-and-python-on-raspberry-pi-2)
- [How to send SMS with GSM module SIM800 and Arduino Uno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839087/how-to-send-sms-with-gsm-module-sim800-and-arduino-uno)
- [Sending GSM Character Set in SMS with SIM800L Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649175/sending-gsm-character-set-in-sms-with-sim800l-module)

The answer in the first one seemed to have worked for him, it didn't work for me.

**What have I tried:**

- I have used the same module with an instance of Docklight serial terminal. SMS sent from Docklight are received on my cellphone and appear as expected, not blank.
- On day 0, before integrating module with Launchpad hardware, I have tested the overall firmware state machine with exact copy of expected responses from SIM800L.
- The results for both the SIM cards are same, except for some of the initial configurations, but I load a typical set of configuration in both of them before I initiate any SMS related task.

Typical values that I use are:

- Echo Off
- CSMP: 17, 167, 0, 0 (I have tried 17, 167, 0, 0, but no luck). Default from SIM 1 is 17,11,0,246, and that from SIM 2 is 17, 255, 0, 0.
- CSCS: "IRA"

**Failed combinations on serial port**:  (SIM 1 and SIM 2)

- CSMP: 17, 11, 0, 246 | CSCS: "IRA" - Sends a blank SMS
- CSMP: 17, 11, 0, 246 | CSCS: "GSM" - Sends a blank SMS
- CSMP: 17, 11, 0, 246 | CSCS: "HEX" - Sends a blank SMS

**Successful combinations on serial port**:  (SIM 1 and SIM 2)

- CSMP: 17, 167, 0, 0  | CSCS: "IRA"
- CSMP: 17, 167, 0, 8  | CSCS: "IRA"
- CSMP: 17, 11, 0, 0   | CSCS: "GSM"
- CSMP: 17, 167, 0, 0  | CSCS: "GSM"
- CSMP: 17, 167, 0, 8  | CSCS: "GSM"

To be honest, I played hunch with these combinations *before* I studied what field reflects what change these combinations (which are poorly documented in the SIM800L User guide).

---

Any idea what I might be missing here? I am open to thinking that it is more of a RTFM (Read The Fat Manual) issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, managed to resolve the issue.

It was not about the SIM800L at all. 
The whole payload was followed by a `'\0'` which is unexpected (I know, very poor on my side). The serial term has no issues with it whatsoever. 
Debugging was fun!